# C# refactoring .vs overloading

Tags: c#

I have a function defined like this:

```
private string AuthOrCharge(ARequest a = null, CRequest c = null, 
                            PACRequest p = null, VRequest v = null,
                            BCRequest b = null, BRRequest cb = null, 
                            BCURequest cub = null, bool ur = false)
```

I want to refactor it to where I can use only 2 parameters:

```
private string AuthOrCharge(Object o, bool ur = false)
```

I will then be able to call it using all the different request objects in the single parameter `o` and then use an `if` statement in the function
to differentiate which one is being passed:

```
private string AuthOrCharge(Object o, bool ur = false)

    //************************
    // do some common stuff for each of the passed types
    // ***********************

    // ***********************
    // Now do the stuff that is different for each type
    // ***********************
    if(o.GetType() == typeof(ARequest))
    {
    }
    else if(o.GetType() == typeof(CRequest))
    {
    }
    else if(o.GetType() == typeof(PACRequest))
    {
    }
    else if(o.GetType() == typeof(VRequest))
    {
    }
    else if(o.GetType() == typeof(BCRequest))
    {
    }
    else if(o.GetType() == typeof(BRRequest))
    {
    }
    else if(o.GetType() == typeof(BCURequest))
    {
    }
    // ***********************
    // do some more common stuff for each of the passed types
    // ***********************

}
```

Comment: Whoa. Should I assume you're doing totally different things with all of these branches, and there's no hope of all the requests implementing a common interface, or having a common base class with a virtual method? Because I'd try to avoid the code you're changing it into. I might [consider abusing `dynamic`](https://swissarmycrowbar.wordpress.com/2016/10/28/dynamic-visitor/) if a virtual method weren't an option. But I don't think I'd go that far.

Comment: I think this should be on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @dymanoid Don't think so, since there is no code to review. If he posted the whole ``AuthOrCharge`` method, than that would be a different story.

Comment: @RandRandom What's that if/else stuff in the question then? IMO "I have these two options that both compile and work, but I can't decide which is less awful" is what we call "primarily opinion based".

Comment: @RandRandom, but this question is about "how to make my code better", there's no functional problem with that.

Comment: In the case were using a better structure (as Ed brought up with base classes and virtual methods) I would highly recommend not doing a giant if else chain like that.  It doesn't save much time over overloading it.  That plus you can document every overload better then you could a method that takes a generic Object.  Besides, while not having the source handy, I have heard that if else like that can cause performance hits.

Comment: That method is clearly doing too much. Like classes should have a single responsibility, methods should also have only a single purpose and not a jack of all trades.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Roll-yer-own runtime overload resolution is a single purpose. Albeit arguably a malign one.

Comment: There is some common code in the `AuthOrCharge` method that is pertinent to every passed type. I'm using the `if` to call different functions within an API based on the passed object. Due to having common code for each, I would rather not build overloads. I've updated the code sample to show.

Comment: Ok, if you have some common code, then the thing to do is to separate that common code out to separate routine(s) and still have separate methods for each type.  See my solution for a change that includes that.

Comment: Well, I've finally got this worked out. I just pass an `Object` and the typing "takes care of itself" Cut around 200 lines from final code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An overload would certainly work better. If the type of request is known at compile time, this would work perfectly:

```
private string AuthOrCharge(ARequest req, bool ur = false) { ... }
private string AuthOrCharge(CRequest req, bool ur = false) { ... }
private string AuthOrCharge(PACRequest req, bool ur = false) { ... }
private string AuthOrCharge(VRequest req, bool ur = false) { ... }
private string AuthOrCharge(BCRequest req, bool ur = false) { ... }
private string AuthOrCharge(BRRequest req, bool ur = false) { ... }
private string AuthOrCharge(BCURequest req, bool ur = false) { ... }
```

If the type is *not* known at compile time, add two more methods:

```
private string AuthOrCharge(object req, bool ur = false) {
    throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown type: {req.GetType()}");
}

private string AuthOrChargeDispatch(dynamic req, bool ur = false) {
    return AuthOrCharge(req, ur);
}
```

Now a call of `AuthOrChargeDispatch` would pick which method to call based on the run-time type of `req`. The overload with `object req` serves as a catch-all implementation that gets activated when a call is being made with a request of some unknown type.

Comment: Good answer. But keep in mind that `dynamic` can have a considerable performance impact.

Comment: It is obvious the type is known at compile time, otherwise his existing solution would not work as the programmer would never know which parameter to stick the object into.

Answer (score 1):

My first choice would be to add an AuthOrCharge method to each of those classes. 
 That is what polymorphism is all about.  You have several different (probably related) classes, you need to perform a similar `AuthOrCharge` method on objects of each of those classes, but the method is different for each class.  So you put that method in each of the classes and at compile time the type of object determines which actual method is called.

But, if for some reason you are not able to get into those classes to change their definition (for example if they are part of a library where you have no access to its code), you can always create extension methods for each, and that would be my second choice.  So I would define an extensions class ...

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string AuthOrCharge(this ARequest ThisRequest, bool ur = false)
    {
    }

    public static string AuthOrCharge(this CRequest ThisRequest, bool ur = false)
    {
    }

    public static string AuthOrCharge(this PACRequest ThisRequest, bool ur = false)
    {
    }

    public static string AuthOrCharge(this VRequest ThisRequest, bool ur = false)
    {
    }

    public static string AuthOrCharge(this BCRequest ThisRequest, bool ur = false)
    {
    }

    public static string AuthOrCharge(this BRRequest ThisRequest, bool ur = false)
    {
    }

    public static string AuthOrCharge(this BCURequest ThisRequest, bool ur = false)
    {
    }
}
```

Then in your code, say you are processing some `ARRequest` called `MyRequest` and you need to call this method with a `ur` of `false`, all you have to do is invoke `MyRequest.AuthOrCharge(false)`.  If you have common code that `AuthOrCharge` performs for all the types, then separate that to a different function that gets called from all these.

```
    public static string AuthOrCharge(this ARequest ThisRequest, bool ur = false)
    {
        ThisRequest.DoCommonAuthOrCharge(ur);
        // do my ARequest specific things here
    }
    ...
    public static string DoCommonAuthOrCharge(this BaseRequest ThisRequest, bool ur = false)
    {
        // do my common things here
    }
```

This assumes that you have a `BaseRequest` class that all your other "request" classes derived from and which holds all the common member and methods, so all those common things can be performed there.

I suspect that you may not have a base request class, and that your first job really is to create one and move all the common things, about these different types, to that base class and change all your request types to derive from it, rather than just defaulting to derive from `object`.

Comment: You won't be able to invoke these extension methods without doing a dynamic type check.

Comment: @Lee - you probably know more about this than I do, but why would you need to do a dynamic type check and how would you do it?  Mind you, the type is known at compile time.  Otherwise his original scheme would not work as the programmer would not know which parameter to use to pass in his object.  So a simple call to `RequestBeingProcessed.AuthOrCharge(true)` should work just fine.

Comment: Ok I see what you're saying but it looks like the question wants to replace the 7 variables in the caller with a single variable of a different type. This approach would work fine with an adapter though.

Comment: I think the question is trying to get away from having to call `AuthOrCharge(null,null, MyARrequest, null, null, null, null, true)` and just be able to call `AuthOrCharge(MyARrequest, true)`.  OP apparently has a function that does something different for each type, but is called with only one of those objects (thus the desire to refactor to a single object), and OP's previous version (unthinkable as it seems) required them to call the function with a bunch of nulls for all the empties.  I am guessing OP realized it was ugly and is looking for a better solution.